# How to read a value from header in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

[image]I want to capture response Header and make it with random value 
location:/en/checkout?booking_token=8559270721578282445909705
How do I extract the token with random value ? Is it possible ? With Regular Extractor ?
Express in regular en/checkout?booking_token=(.*)

Comment: I use the structure, but Jmeter do not accept the variable for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible:

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above header
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: the safest way would be `Main sample and sub-samples`
   - Field to check: `Response Headers`
   - Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `booking_token`
   - Regular Expression: `booking_token=(\d+)`
   - Template: `$1$`

     [image]
3. That's it, now you should be able to access the extracted value as [`${booking_token}`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) where required:

   [image]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)